# Map that extends TreeMap deserialized as empty map on client

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I need to pass a map with a custom field to client.

just TreeMap works fine, but not descendants of TreeMap. If I change TreeMap to HashMap, it also works fine.
GWT 2.5.1

```
public class MyMap extends TreeMap<String, String> {

    public String s;

    public MyMap() {
    }

    public MyMap(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}

public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GreetingService {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> testSelfMap() {
        Map<String, String> c = new MyMap("abc");
        c.put("k", "v");
        return c;
    }
}

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
    Map<String, String> testSelfMap();
}

public interface GreetingServiceAsync {
    void testSelfMap(AsyncCallback<Map<String, String>> async);
}

public class HW implements EntryPoint {
    GreetingServiceAsync serv = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        serv.testSelfMap(new AsyncCallback<Map<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Map<String, String> result) {
                System.out.println(result.get("k"));
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                caught.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a dummy service method that returns a `MyMap` explicitly? This forces GWT to serializa that `MyMap` instead of just `Map`.

Comment: @Churro I tried. That didn't help

Comment: It's a bug in `TreeMap_CustomFieldSerializer`: they put the `comparator` to the stream in `serialize()` and take it from the stream in `instantiate()`. `instantiate()` is not called for descendants.